# how to Convert the String to nsutf8 encode

Tags: ios, objective-c, utf-8

```
NSString *phone = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"phone=%@",[paymentServerData valueForKey:@"phone"]];
NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"key=%@",[paymentServerData valueForKey:@"key"]];
NSString *furl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"furl=%@",[paymentServerData valueForKey:@"furl"]];
NSString *txnid = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"txnid=%@",[paymentServerData valueForKey:@"txnid"]];
NSString *productinfo =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"productinfo=%@",[paymentServerData valueForKey:@"txnid"]];

 NSArray *arrayString = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects phone, key,furl,txnid,productinfoEncode,nil];
NSString *postString = [arrayString componentsJoinedByString:@"&"];

NSString *address = @"https://secure.payu.in/_payment";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: address];
NSString *body = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@", postString];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL: url];
[request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody: body]; 
[_paymentWebView loadRequest: request];
```

i have 5 parameters to pass the body string but i want encode only one parameter  how to encode one parameter and send the body method.

help me to encode this **productionfo** string.

Comment: NSData *postData = [postString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES]; add this line and pass postData in your body .

Comment: Thanks for your response. but i dont want convert all postString. i want only encode **productinfo** only .

Comment: then check my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

```
// this line for encoding your data . 
NSData *postData = [productinfo dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES]; 

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"URL"];
NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[theRequest setHTTPBody:postData];
```

Comment: NSData *postData = [productinfo dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES]; post this line before NSArray *arrayString = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects phone, key,furl,txnid,productinfoEncode,nil];

Comment: @Mathi ok fine your problem solve then approve my answer and give up vote . Thank you.

Comment: objc[16967]: Class PLBuildVersion is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices (0x11f48b998) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PhotoLibraryServices.framework/PhotoLibraryServices (0x11f2b0d38). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

Comment: @Mathi did you use perform some functionality like select image from gallery or camera ? this error because of that .

Comment: no i dont do. what i will try to archive is have some parameter convert only one parameter in encode formate. which we did above. i run my program it show this error

Comment: i think this is the error reason... **body** is string so it show **incompatible pointer types sending 'Nsstring to parameter of type NSData'**

Comment: @Mathi update your question with mine code use. so i can easily find whats actual problem .